# Método .load do JS não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, fiz esse código para testar, pórem ele não funciona

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#div").load('teste.php');
    });
});
</script>

<input type="button" id="button" name="button" value="ADD PAGE">
<div id="div" name="div"></div>
```

teste.php

```
<?php>
echo 'teste';
?>
```

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+J` no navegador, recarrega a página e vê se aparece algum erro.

Comment: @RafaelMafra Retorna `teste:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at teste (teste:14)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (teste:19)`

Comment: O código me parece correto. Veja se importou o jquery corretamente no head da página

Answer (score 1):

O problema esta que eu não chamei o JQuery.

Apenas adicionei essa linha:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Se essa segunda linha não for de script seu,  é desnecessária.